# Day of month in xarray

Tags: python, datetime, dataset, python-xarray, dayofmonth

I have dataset data and I found anomaly so the result was data array with coordinates (longitude, latitude) and time and the time as number of year.

How to change the Time as 1 June , 2 June... so far?

[screenshot of `xarray.DataArray`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbokv.png)

Answer (score 0):

i think you could just do

`pandas.to_datetime(x['time'],origin=datetime.datetime(2020,1,1),unit="D")`

(this assumes the int is day number of this year and jan 1 == 0)

Comment: thank you , But I not need the year only month and day I need

Comment: `dates = pandas.to_datetime(x['time'],origin=datetime.datetime(2020,1,1),unit="D");dates.year;dates.month` I guess?